# aws cli cannot execute ecr commands

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I was using the lastest version of the aws cli instralled via pip (and have since downgraded to 1.10.19 as a teem member can execute the following commands) and was not able to use ecr commands.

I am attempting to follow the prompt after creating a repo in ecr `aws ecr get-login` but the aws cli is saying ecr is an invalid choice. As stated, other devs on my team have access to this command through the aws cli. I don't see anything on my IAM persmissions that would suggest not even being able to see that as an option through the cli commands.

Any suggestions?

The EXACT error:

```
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [parameters]
aws: error: argument command: Invalid choice, valid choices are:

autoscaling                              | cloudformation                          
cloudfront                               | cloudhsm                                
cloudsearch                              | cloudsearchdomain                       
cloudtrail                               | cloudwatch                              
codecommit                               | codepipeline                            
cognito-identity                         | cognito-sync                            
datapipeline                             | devicefarm                              
directconnect                            | ds                                      
dynamodb                                 | dynamodbstreams                         
ec2                                      | ecs                                     
efs                                      | elasticache                             
elasticbeanstalk                         | elastictranscoder                       
elb                                      | emr                                     
glacier                                  | iam                                     
importexport                             | kinesis                                 
kms                                      | lambda                                  
logs                                     | machinelearning                         
opsworks                                 | rds                                     
redshift                                 | route53                                 
route53domains                           | sdb                                     
ses                                      | sns                                     
sqs                                      | ssm                                     
storagegateway                           | sts                                     
support                                  | swf                                     
workspaces                               | s3api                                   
s3                                       | configure                               
deploy                                   | configservice                           
help
```

Comment: Works fine for me with aws --version showing aws-cli/1.11.45.

Comment: Same issue for version: `aws-cli/1.2.9` but it works with version `aws-cli/1.11.126`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update your AWS CLI tool installation. You can run `aws --version` to see what version you currently have installed.

Comment: full reinstall through homebrew and pip resolved the issue.